# Using "And" for cypher in Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a cypher query that looks like this:

```
start n = node:node_auto_index(Department = "IT") match (n)-->(x) Where x.Name = "Mike" And x.Occupation = "Developer" return x;
```

This returns all nodes related to the root node if the Name is Mike and the Occupation is developer.

Now how do I do the "And x.Occupation" in C#?

```
var query = this.clientConnection
      .Cypher
      .Start(new
      {
         n = Node.ByIndexLookup("node_auto_index", "Department", "IT")
      })
      .Match("n-->x")
      .Where((Employee x) => x.Name == "Version" //"AND" x.Occupation = "Developer)
      .Return<Node<IQS_Content_Manager.Models.Nodes.Version>>("(x)")
      .Results;

queryResult = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Where((Employee x) => x.Name == "Version")
.AndWhere((Employee x) => x.Occupation == "Developer)
```